# Executing a sequence of actions over time in Unity

Tags: c#, api, unity3d, easing

This script executes a sequence of actions over time and is based on the methods exposed by the UrhoSharp framework. I am new to Unity, but well acquainted with C# so I know what I'm doing for the most part. I'm primarily concerned with performance. Is this how such problems are usually approached in Unity or can we do better?

Using [the functions published here](https://gist.github.com/cjddmut/d789b9eb78216998e95c), I was able to make `Vector3` interpolations work. I will be honest and admit I know nothing about quaternions so I just use Unity's built-in helper function for linear interpolations and throw an exception if some other interpolation is specified.

Ultimately, this solution aims to provide a proper framework for animating anything in a easy to understand way.

This is how you'd use it.

```
myGameObject.AddComponent<Animate>()
    .Begin(Repeat.Forever,
        new MoveTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), myGameObject.transform.position + new Vector3(15, 0, 0), Easing.EaseInBounce, TransformOrigin.World),
        new DelayTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)),
        new MoveTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), myGameObject.transform.position, Easing.EaseOutQuint, TransformOrigin.World),
        new DelayTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)),
        new MoveTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), myGameObject.transform.position - new Vector3(15, 0, 0), Easing.EaseInBack, TransformOrigin.World),
        new DelayTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)),
        new MoveTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), myGameObject.transform.position, Easing.Spring, TransformOrigin.World),
        new DelayTime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)));
```

Or to perform actions in parallel:

```
myGameObject.AddComponent<Animate>()
    .Begin(Repeat.Forever, new Parallel(
        new MoveTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), myGameObject.transform.position - new Vector3(0, 5, 0)), 
        new ScaleTo(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), Vector3.zero)));
```

And here is the code (not including [the code here](https://gist.github.com/cjddmut/d789b9eb78216998e95c)).

**Animate**:

```
public class Animate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public const Repeat DefaultRepeat = Repeat.Once;

    class ActionSequence
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The actions to perform.
        /// </summary>
        readonly ActionBase[] _actions;

        /// <summary>
        /// The current action.
        /// </summary>
        public ActionBase Current;

        /// <summary>
        /// The arguments to evaluate for the current action.
        /// </summary>
        public object[] CurrentArguments;

        /// <summary>
        /// The index of the current action.
        /// </summary>
        public uint CurrentIndex = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// The "journey" of the current action.
        /// </summary>
        public float CurrentJourney = 0;

        /// <summary>
        /// Whether or not the current action has started.
        /// </summary>
        public bool CurrentStarted;

        /// <summary>
        /// The number of actions in the sequence.
        /// </summary>
        public readonly uint Length;

        /// <summary>
        /// The manner in which the sequence of actions should repeat.
        /// </summary>
        public Repeat Repeat;

        public ActionSequence(Repeat repeat, ActionBase[] actions)
        {
            _actions = actions;
            Current = _actions[0];
            Length = Convert.ToUInt32(_actions.Length);
            Repeat = repeat;
        }

        public ActionBase this[uint index]
        {
            get
            {
                return _actions[index];
            }
        }

        public void Next()
        {
            CurrentArguments = null;
            CurrentIndex++;
            CurrentJourney = 0;
            CurrentStarted = false;
        }
    }

    public enum Repeat
    {
        Once,
        Forever
    }

    List<ActionSequence> _sequences = new List<ActionSequence>();

    void Update()
    {
        var count = _sequences.Count;

        if (count == 0)
            return;

        var deltaTime = Time.deltaTime;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var sequence = _sequences[i];

            if (sequence.Current.Duration <= TimeSpan.Zero)
                goto Done;

            if (!sequence.CurrentStarted)
            {
                sequence.CurrentArguments = sequence.Current.GetArguments(gameObject);
                sequence.CurrentStarted = true;
            }

            if (sequence.CurrentJourney >= sequence.Current.Duration.TotalSeconds)
                goto Done;

            sequence.CurrentJourney += deltaTime;
            sequence.Current.Update(gameObject, deltaTime, sequence.CurrentJourney, sequence.CurrentArguments);

            continue;

            //Is the action done?
            Done:
            {
                //If so, get the next
                sequence.Next();
                if (sequence.Repeat == Repeat.Forever)
                {
                    //If done, prepare for next iteration
                    if (sequence.CurrentIndex == sequence.Length)
                        sequence.CurrentIndex = 0;

                    //Get next action now so we don't have to on subsequent updates
                    sequence.Current = sequence[sequence.CurrentIndex];
                }
                else if (sequence.Repeat == Repeat.Once)
                {
                    //If done, remove current sequence
                    if (sequence.CurrentIndex == sequence.Length)
                    {
                        _sequences.RemoveAt(i);
                        count--;
                        i--;
                    }
                    //Otherwise, get next action now so we don't have to on subsequent updates
                    else sequence.Current = sequence[sequence.CurrentIndex];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the given sequence of actions once.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="actions"></param>
    public void Begin(params ActionBase[] actions)
    {
        Begin(DefaultRepeat, actions);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the given sequence of actions once or forever.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="repeat"></param>
    /// <param name="actions"></param>
    public void Begin(Repeat repeat, params ActionBase[] actions)
    {
        var sequence = new ActionSequence(repeat, actions);
        _sequences.Add(sequence);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Performs the given sequence of actions in parallel once.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="repeat"></param>
    /// <param name="actions"></param>
    public void Begin(Parallel parallel)
    {
        Begin(DefaultRepeat, parallel);
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Performs the given sequence of actions in parallel once or forever.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="repeat"></param>
    /// <param name="parallel"></param>
    public void Begin(Repeat repeat, Parallel parallel)
    {
        for (uint i = 0; i < parallel.Count; i++)
            Begin(repeat, parallel[i]);
    }
}
```

**ActionBase** + some base actions:

```
public abstract class ActionBase
{
    protected readonly TimeSpan _duration;
    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get
        {
            return _duration;
        }
    }

    protected ActionBase(TimeSpan duration)
    {
        _duration = duration;
    }

    internal abstract object[] GetArguments(GameObject go);

    internal abstract void Update(GameObject go, float deltaTime, float journey, object[] arguments);
}

public abstract class Interpolate<TValue> : ActionBase
{
    protected readonly Easing _easing;

    protected readonly TValue _target;

    protected Interpolate(TimeSpan duration, TValue target, Easing easing) : base(duration)
    {
        _easing = easing;
        _target = target;
    }

    protected float GetValue(Easing easing, float origin, float target, float percent)
    {
        switch (_easing)
        {
            case Easing.EaseInBack:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInBack(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInBounce:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInBounce(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInCirc:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInCirc(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInCubic:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInCubic(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInElastic:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInElastic(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInExpo:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInExpo(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInOutBack:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInOutBack(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInOutBounce:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInOutBounce(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInOutCirc:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInOutCirc(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInOutCubic:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInOutCubic(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInOutElastic:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInOutElastic(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInOutExpo:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInOutExpo(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInOutQuad:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInOutQuad(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInOutQuart:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInOutQuart(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInOutQuint:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInOutQuint(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInOutSine:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInOutSine(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInQuad:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInQuad(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInQuart:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInQuart(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInQuint:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInQuint(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseInSine:
                return EasingFunction.EaseInSine(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseOutBack:
                return EasingFunction.EaseOutBack(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseOutBounce:
                return EasingFunction.EaseOutBounce(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseOutCirc:
                return EasingFunction.EaseOutCirc(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseOutCubic:
                return EasingFunction.EaseOutCubic(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseOutElastic:
                return EasingFunction.EaseOutElastic(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseOutExpo:
                return EasingFunction.EaseOutExpo(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseOutQuad:
                return EasingFunction.EaseOutQuad(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseOutQuart:
                return EasingFunction.EaseOutQuart(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseOutQuint:
                return EasingFunction.EaseOutQuint(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.EaseOutSine:
                return EasingFunction.EaseOutSine(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.Linear:
                return EasingFunction.Linear(origin, target, percent);
            case Easing.Spring:
                return EasingFunction.Spring(origin, target, percent);
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    protected abstract TValue GetValue(TValue origin, float percent);

    protected abstract void SetValue(GameObject go, TValue value);

    internal override void Update(GameObject go, float deltaTime, float journey, object[] arguments)
    {
        var origin = (TValue)arguments[0];
        var percent = Mathf.Clamp01(journey / Convert.ToSingle(_duration.TotalSeconds));
        var value = GetValue(origin, percent);
        SetValue(go, value);
    }
}

public abstract class InterpolateVector3 : Interpolate<Vector3>
{
    protected InterpolateVector3(TimeSpan duration, Vector3 target, Easing easing) : base(duration, target, easing) { }

    protected override Vector3 GetValue(Vector3 origin, float percent)
    {
        var value = new float[3];
        for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            var origin_
                = i == 0
                ? origin.x
                : i == 1
                ? origin.y
                : origin.z;

            var target_
                = i == 0
                ? _target.x
                : i == 1
                ? _target.y
                : _target.z;

            value[i] = GetValue(_easing, origin_, target_, percent);
        }
        return new Vector3(value[0], value[1], value[2]);
    }
}

public abstract class InterpolateVector4 : Interpolate<Vector4>
{
    protected InterpolateVector4(TimeSpan duration, Vector3 target, Easing easing) : base(duration, target, easing) { }

    protected override Vector4 GetValue(Vector4 origin, float percent)
    {
        var value = new float[4];
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var origin_
                = i == 0
                ? origin.w
                : i == 1
                ? origin.x
                : i == 2
                ? origin.y
                : origin.z;

            var target_
                = i == 0
                ? _target.w
                : i == 1
                ? _target.x
                : i == 2
                ? _target.y
                : _target.z;

            value[i] = GetValue(_easing, origin_, target_, percent);
        }
        return new Vector4(value[0], value[1], value[2], value[3]);
    }
}

public abstract class InterpolateQuaternion : Interpolate<Quaternion>
{
    protected InterpolateQuaternion(TimeSpan duration, Quaternion target, Easing easing) : base(duration, target, easing) { }

    protected override Quaternion GetValue(Quaternion origin, float percent)
    {
        switch (_easing)
        {
            case Easing.Linear:
                return Quaternion.Lerp(origin, _target, percent);
        }
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Some default actions:

```
public class DelayTime : ActionBase
{
    public DelayTime(TimeSpan duration) : base(duration) { }

    internal override object[] GetArguments(GameObject go)
    {
        return default(object[]);
    }

    internal override void Update(GameObject go, float deltaTime, float journey, object[] arguments) { }
}

public class MoveTo : InterpolateVector3
{
    protected readonly TransformOrigin _transformOrigin;

    public MoveTo(TimeSpan duration, Vector3 target, Easing easing = Easing.Linear, TransformOrigin transformOrigin = TransformOrigin.Local) : base(duration, target, easing)
    {
        _transformOrigin = transformOrigin;
    }

    internal override object[] GetArguments(GameObject go)
    {
        return new object[]
        {
            _transformOrigin == TransformOrigin.Local
            ? go.transform.localPosition
            : go.transform.position
        };
    }

    protected override void SetValue(GameObject go, Vector3 value)
    {
        switch (_transformOrigin)
        {
            case TransformOrigin.Local:
                go.transform.localPosition = value;
                break;
            case TransformOrigin.World:
                go.transform.position = value;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class RotateTo : InterpolateQuaternion
{
    protected readonly TransformOrigin _transformOrigin;

    public RotateTo(TimeSpan duration, Quaternion target, Easing easing = Easing.Linear, TransformOrigin transformOrigin = TransformOrigin.Local) : base(duration, target, easing)
    {
        _transformOrigin = transformOrigin;
    }

    internal override object[] GetArguments(GameObject go)
    {
        return new object[]
        {
            _transformOrigin == TransformOrigin.Local
            ? go.transform.localRotation
            : go.transform.rotation
        };
    }

    protected override void SetValue(GameObject go, Quaternion value)
    {
        switch (_transformOrigin)
        {
            case TransformOrigin.Local:
                go.transform.localRotation = value;
                break;
            case TransformOrigin.World:
                go.transform.rotation = value;
                break;
        }
    }
}

public class ScaleTo : InterpolateVector3
{
    public ScaleTo(TimeSpan duration, Vector3 target, Easing easing = Easing.Linear) : base(duration, target, easing) { }

    internal override object[] GetArguments(GameObject go)
    {
        return new object[]
        {
            go.transform.localScale
        };
    }

    protected override void SetValue(GameObject go, Vector3 value)
    {
        go.transform.localScale = value;
    }
}
```

For executing actions in parallel:

```
public class Parallel
{
    readonly ActionBase[] _actions;

    public uint Count
    {
        get
        {
            return Convert.ToUInt32(_actions.Length);
        }
    }

    public Parallel(params ActionBase[] actions)
    {
        _actions = actions;
    }

    public ActionBase this[uint index]
    {
        get
        {
            return _actions[index];
        }
    }
}
```

Other:

```
public enum TransformOrigin
{
    Local,
    World
}
```

Comment: This isn't directly related to a code review, but just because you said you are new to Unity, I wanted to point out a few existing tweening libraries, such as [DoTween, GoKit, iTween, LeanTween](https://github.com/RyanNielson/awesome-unity#tweening). Personally I'm using DoTween and the source is on GitHub. If you are concerned about performance, LeanTween emphasizes that it is efficient and lightweight. In case you don't get a response here, it may be good to review these libraries' code to get a sense of how things are done there.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations. Why isn't this related to code review? I published my code and I'm asking the community to review it? Personally, I won't fuss with DoTween or any library I have to pay for. I might go with iTween since it is free, but it would still be nice to learn how this all works.

Comment: Oops sorry, I meant my comment isn't related to code review. Your post is fine of course. All the libraries I mentioned are free (though DoTween does have a "Pro" version). iTween is one of the most popular options, though I think it's also known for having a messy codebase. I've used both DOTween and iTween and I find DOTween much easier to use. I definitely think it's good to learn how it all works. I was just suggesting that you go look at the source code of these libraries to see how it works, and how they did it differently compared to you.

Comment: Here is the [DOTween GitHub repository](https://github.com/Demigiant/dotween) and here is the [LeanTween Github repository](https://github.com/dentedpixel/LeanTween)

Answer (score 1):

#### Review

- Your system is timespan based. This is fine, but I would opt for a time-indexed system completely independant of any time unit. You could then provide a callback function that provides the timespan for a single time unit `() => Time.deltaTime;` or alternatively with the index as argument, so you could skew time if you desire to `(index) => index * Time.deltaTime;`. I like being independant from actual time and work with discrete time instead. It allows flexibility in defining time.
- The easing functions look alright, I would only refactor `Animate` and its nested class `ActionSequence`.
- The fields of `ActionSequence` should be (almost-)immutable properties, or at least unmodifiable from a public perspective. State should only change through methods, this enforces integrity and encapsulation.
- `Next` should have a circular incrementation `CurrentIndex = CurrentIndex + 1 % Length;`
- `ActionSequence` should know whether is has completed, based on `CurrentIndex`, `Length` and `Repeat`.
- `Animate.Update` should be cleaned up. Much of the behavior should be forwared to a `sequence` instance. This would provide better encapsulation.
- These `goto Done;`, `continue;` statements should be refactored because you have made some spaghetti code here. It's hard to read method `Update` like this.
- `_sequences.RemoveAt(i);` should be replaced by having a flag on a sequence `IsCompleted`. I would not modify the instance assignmens in the array. Using LINQ with `Where(!IsCompleted)` reads much better.
- You might want to think about a recursive structure where an action migth have 0 or more sequences, each containing 1 or more actions. You'd be able to design much more complex scenarios.